# xcode project paused when i run app simulator in Debug

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

Debug shows me this

```
  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

and the output shows

```
2013-05-16 04:58:07.496 Scroll Blog[5296:c07] get_recent_post&cat=
2013-05-16 04:58:12.251 Scroll Blog[5296:c07] -JSONValue failed. Error is: No digits in exponent
2013-05-16 04:58:12.252 Scroll Blog[5296:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x28eb012 0x2207e7e 0x289eb6a 0x289ea20 0xb43c 0x12796 0xe3726 0x221b6b0 0x1c47765 0x286ef3f 0x286e96f 0x2891734 0x2890f44 0x2890e1b 0x28457e3 0x2845668 0x114bffc 0x2f3d 0x2e65 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: You're trying to insert an object that is `nil` to an array.  Did you read your error?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the error immediately before the exception: "-JSONValue failed. Error is: No digits in exponent"

Answer (score 0):

Try [Adding an Exception Breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html). Now you should get a more useful stack trace.

Comment: I was about to state that this is useful but it isn't an answer to the question. Then I realized that there is no question.

Comment: Thanks for answers .. i found something strange  i install seam wordpress plugin and run the xcode in my hosting company and it work i change the hosting company and the problem come !!!